# Passing values from HTML form to Python Flask

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I've already seen this question, but my code still doesn't work. I have 3 files (main.py and add.html are important here).

The user enters book name, author and rating (in '/add'), and the given values should be passed to main.py and printed out. But it gives me an 400 error, even thou I gave the needed values in add.html and in main.py.

Can someone help me find what's wrong?

Thanks.

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

all_books = []


@app.route('/')
def home():
  return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add():
  book_name = request.form['bookName']
  book_author = request.form['book-author']
  book_rating = request.form['book-rating']
  return f"<h1>Name: {book_name}, Author: {book_author}, Rating: {book_rating}</h1>"


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Library</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My Library</h1>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    
<a href="{{ url_for('add') }}">Add New Book</a>
</body>
</html>
```

add.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add Book</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="/add" method="post">
    <label>Book Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="bookName" name="book-name">
    <label>Book Author</label>
    <input type="text" id="book-author" name="book-author">
    <label>Rating</label>
    <input type="text" id="book-rating" name="book-rating">
    <button type="submit">Add Book</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The form action should not be `action="/add"` but `action="add"` I guess.

Comment: Sadly it isn't.

Comment: Try capitalizing "post"

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: @walker Works even if "post" is written like this, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you try to use the `/add` route for two things, first trying to display the `add.html` page and second processing the form on that page. You need to separate these two by creating a separate route for displaying the page.

Code:

```py
@app.route('/add')
def add():
  return render_template('add.html')

@app.route('/added', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def added():
  book_name = request.form['book-name']
  book_author = request.form['book-author']
  book_rating = request.form['book-rating']
  return f"<h1>Name: {book_name}, Author: {book_author}, Rating: {book_rating}</h1>"
```

Now call `/added` from the form in `add.html`:

```html
<form action="/added" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found out a solution to the problem without adding a new route as @Marijn did. I changed the route in index.html to be dynamic. Here is the code for main.py and add.html:

I also changed the part where instead of printing it out it adds it as a dictionary to a list (this doesn't have anything to do with the question so don't mind that part).

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

all_books = []


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html", books=all_books)


@app.route("/add", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add():
    if request.method == "POST":
        new_book = {
            "title": request.form["title"],
            "author": request.form["author"],
            "rating": request.form["rating"]
        }
        all_books.append(new_book)
    return render_template("add.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

add.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add Book</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{{ url_for('add') }}" method="POST">
        <label>Book Name</label>
        <input name="title" type="text">
        <label>Book Author</label>
        <input name="author" type="text">
        <label>Rating</label>
        <input name="rating" type="text">
        <button type="submit">Add Book</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```